# docker Illegal instruction(core dumped) when import mxnet from the image ufomy/deepo

Tags: docker, mxnet

I used docker and deepo from this website:  https://github.com/ufoym/deepo#GPU,
When I start the container, I can import all the frameworks (tensorflow, caffe, pytorch)except mxnet. I don't know why. What should I do?

The error can be seen from this picture: Illegal instruction(core dumped)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is an issue created on the Github repo already for the issue you're seeing: https://github.com/ufoym/deepo/issues/53. You may try an older version of the image, or reaching out to ufoym.

You could also use the containers at https://hub.docker.com/r/mxnet/python/